# Adding multiple results from MySQL together with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I am doing a big project and I've come to a blank...(writers block).

I'm trying too add a time sheet page. I have a database with JobID, StartTime, FinishTime. I can get the total time for one day fine, but I want to add all the days together?

I'm storing the times in the database as date('U')

[Print screen of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpHzg.png)

This is what I have:

```
    echo "<a href=''>Arrvied on site</a><BR><a href=''>Left site</a></font>";
echo "<BR><BR><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr>
        <td>Start</td>
        <td>Finish</td>
    </tr>";
$Total = "";    

$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobtime WHERE `jobid` LIKE " . $JID) or die(mysql_error());  
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array( $result3 )) {


    echo "<tr>
        <td>" . date('H:i', $row3['start']) . "</td>
        <td>" . date('H:i', $row3['finish']) . "</td>
        <td>" . date('D d/m/Y', $row3['finish']). "</td>
        <td>" . date('H:i', $row3['finish']-$row3['start']). "</td>
    </tr>";

  $thistotal = $row3['finish']-$row3['start'];
  $Total = Total + $thistotal;

}

echo "</table><BR>Total: " . date('H:i',$Total) . " Hours<HR>";
```

Obviously it is only showing the last entry.

Please help!

Comment: You could calculate the total inside the loop, and then echo it outside the loop, or attach an ID to that html column and use a bit of JavaScript to sum values that appear within it. Whatever you do, DON'T use PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can pick the bones out of this...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
     <table id='mytable'>
      <tr>
       <td>Project</td>
       <td>Workstage</td>
       <td>Hours</td>
       <td>Description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td><input size=3 id='total' disabled='disabled'/></td>
       <td></td>
      </tr>
       <tr id='row0' class="row">
       <td>
                      <select class="project" name="">
                          <option value="">Select One</option>
                        </select>
    </td><td>
                       <select class="task" name="" onchange="updateText('task')">
                           <option value="">Select One</option>
                      </select>
       </td>
       <td>
         <select name = 'hours' onmouseup="sumInputs()">
         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

         for(var d=0;d<=16;d++)
         {
             document.write("<option>"+(d/2).toFixed(1)+"</option>");
         }
         </script>
         </select>
       <td><input type="text" value="" class="taskText" /></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
       <input type="button" onclick="cloneRow()" value="Add Row" />
    </form>

  </body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>var rowNum =1;

       function cloneRow() {
          var row = document.getElementById("row0"); // find row to copy
          var table = document.getElementById("mytable"); // find table to append to
          var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
          clone.id = "row"+rowNum; // change id or other attributes/contents
          table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
          initProject(clone.id);
          rowNum++;
        }

        function createRow() {
          var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create row node
          var col = document.createElement('td'); // create column node
          var col2 = document.createElement('td'); // create second column node
          row.appendChild(col); // append first column to row
          row.appendChild(col2); // append second column to row
          col.innerHTML = "qwe"; // put data in first column
          col2.innerHTML = "rty"; // put data in second column
          var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"); // find table to append to
          table.appendChild(row); // append row to table
        }



    window.sumInputs = function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByName('hours'),
            result = document.getElementById('total'),
            sum = 0;

        for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
            var ip = inputs[i];

            if (ip.name && ip.name.indexOf("total") < 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(ip.value) || 0;
            }

        }

        result.value = sum;
    }


    var myJson =
    {
       "listItems":[
          {
             "id":"1",
             "project_no":"1001",
             "task":[
                {
                   "task_description":"Folding stuff",
                   "id":"111",
                   "task_summary":"Folding",
                   "hours":"0.0"
                },
                {
                   "task_description":"Drawing stuff",
                   "id":"222",
                   "task_summary":"Drawing",
                   "hours":"0.0"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "id":"2",
             "project_no":"1002",
             "task":[
                {
                   "task_description":"Meeting description",
                   "id":"333",
                   "task_summary":"Meeting",
                   "hours":"0.0"
                },
                {
                   "task_description":"Administration",
                   "id":"444",
                   "task_summary":"Admin",
                   "hours":"0.0"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }

    function initProject(rowId){

    console.log(rowId);
        if(rowId == 'row0'){
         $.each(myJson.listItems, function (index, value) {

            $("#"+rowId+" .project").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.project_no+'</option>');
          });
        }
        $('#'+rowId+' .project').on('change', function(e){
            rowElem = e.target.closest(".row");


         $('#'+rowId+' .task').html('<option value="000">Select One</option>');
          for(var i = 0; i < myJson.listItems.length; i++)
          {

            if(myJson.listItems[i].id == $(this).val())
            {
               $.each(myJson.listItems[i].task, function (index, value) {
                  $('#'+rowId+' .task').append('<option value="'+value.id+'" data-description="'+value.task_description+'">'+value.task_summary+'</option>');
              });
            }
          }
      });

      $('#'+rowId+' .task').change(function() {
      $('#'+rowId+' .taskText').val( $(this).find('option:selected').data('description') )
    })
    }
    initProject('row0');
</script>
```